# Translation: couldn't organise a piss-up in a brewery, etc

Tags: translation, equivalent-phrase

Looking for a colloquial Chinese translation of the English: **Couldn't organise a piss up in a brewery**

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/couldn%27t_organise_a_piss-up_in_a_brewery):

> Presents an example of a minimally simple project that the person or group described is presumed unable to accomplish.
>
> couldn't organise a piss-up in a brewery
>
> `(UK, Australia, New Zealand, vulgar, slang, idiomatic) Is unable even to organise a project that requires no planning; is incompetent.  [quotations ▼]`

> **Synonyms**
>
> `couldn't organise a two-ticket raffle`
>
> `couldn't organise an orgy in a brothel`
>
> `couldn't organise a bun fight in a bakery`
>
> `couldn't pour water out of a boot`

- What phrases are there in Chinese to express this kind of incompetence, i.e.: unable to organize something that doesn't involve any planning?

(*Specifically talking about someones organization skills, of course.*)

Comment: Do you prefer that the phrase be very vulgar?

Comment: Can't hurt, won't hurt

Comment: I am almost certain an exact counterpart in Chinese doesn't exist, in which case it would be helpful to clarify the context in more detail, such as the person you're trying to describe is in high position or an ordinary Joe, as well as how rude is the expression you expect.

Comment: Just anything that describes someone with no organizational skills.

Comment: Oxford funnily enough has this entry: he couldn't organize a piss-up in a brewery
他即使到了酒厂都组织不了大家狂喝痛饮

Comment: Can you accept one of the answers?  Or can you clarify your question further?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty What's unclear?

Comment: @user3306356  It is unclear to me why you have not accepted an answer.  They seem to me to answer your question.  If they do you should accept one.  If not you should say why not.

Comment: Waiting to see if, like the question asks, there are any answers more specifically talking about organizational skills.

Comment: Max Mandarin addresses that, and the comment by pheiztu takes it further since an emperor is really not required to be a general or an economist or even political strategist -- rather he must be able to organize people with those skills. What do you think of his answer?

Comment: I came across 小小事也安排不好，連一點小事也辦不了 today from Cambridge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

昏庸无能 is very close.
it means:
have no ability to do even a very simple project.
have no management skill to manage a team.

Comment: As native speaker I would like to point out that the phrase "昏庸无能" is usually used to describe a emperor.

Answer (score 4):

一事无成This may seem a little different from what you want when translated directly,which is 'haven't done anything meaningful'.But,it is often used to describe a pernson who can't accomplish even the easiest assignment.I believe it's a pretty close one.

Comment: "achieved nothing in life" is not the same with "incompetent".

Comment: Yeah,一无是处is better.

Answer (score 4):

The Chinese only have the plain and dry "组织能力差".

As for translation, there is a direct translation with a few touch-ups:

> 就算带一群酒鬼到酒坊里，他也没能力组织到让大家喝个痛快。

Added 酒鬼 because the Chinese is a less bibulous people, at least on paper.

A direct translation is good in this case because there is no comparable idioms exist in Chinese.